# Codeigniter Change Fetched Date format in View

Tags: php, codeigniter, date

I have a date value from database as `12-12-2015`
I tried the below code

```
$date = "12-12-2015";
echo date("M d, Y", strtotime($date));
```

it gives an output as `Dec 12, 2015`, but i want `December 12, 2015` as output
Thanks on advance

Comment: $date = "12-12-2015";
echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($date));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Date Format to Month Name and Year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18635051/php-date-format-to-month-name-and-year)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just near to Output. In date format function use F for Full month Display.

```
$date = "12-12-2015";
echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$date = "12-12-2015";
echo date("F d, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Reference Link:http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks..If my answer was helpful then accept it by clicking right marker and give up vote. This is the best way to appreciate the answer.